# How to subscribe to MS Graph events created in non primary calendar?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I've created an app that works with MS Graph API for MS outlook events and have sync based on notifications. Notifications works fine for events that were created in `primary` calendar but if event was created in different from `primary` notifications will not be sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe calendars other than primary. In the **resource** property add the resource you want to create subscription for. You can do something like this:

```
{
   "changeType": "created",
   "notificationUrl": "https://webhook.azurewebsites.net/api/send/myNotifyClient",
   "resource": "me/calendars/<calendarId>/events",
   "expirationDateTime":"2016-11-20T18:23:45.9356913Z",
   "clientState": "secretClientValue",
   "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2"
}
```